# Trouble with Jquery and bxslider with magento

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento, bxslider

I am having trouble with a jquery extension called bxslider,

the images in the slider do not seem to change. and i do not know why.

I am using magento, so there could be a trouble with prototype and jquery conflicted but i do not think so.

Here is the website [www.f4funky.com](http://www.f4funky.com)

if someone could check the website that would be great

The relevant code seems to modify my mark up. but i cant see any errors with why it will not work

here is the javacscript

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_JS),'jquery.bxSlider.min.js'?>"></script>

<script>
var jQuery_1_8_2 = jQuery.noConflict(true);

jQuery_1_8_2(document).ready(function(){
 jQuery_1_8_2('#slider1').bxSlider({
 infiniteLoop: false,
hideControlOnEnd: true,
auto:true,
slideWidth:960
});
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting jQuery into noConflict mode, then using the jQuery() function wrapper so you can continue to use the standard `$` with jQuery:

```
<script>
$.noConflict();
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
    $('#slider1').bxSlider({
        infiniteLoop: false,
        hideControlOnEnd: true,
        auto:true,
        slideWidth:960
    });
});
</script>
```